# Multiple Custom Validation Constraint in Symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.3

I created multiple validators using de [oficial documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) and all of them works fine, but only when I use separately.
In a bundle I defined this:

```
# Resources/config/validation.ynl
SF\SomeBundle\Entity\SomeEntity:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - SF\UtilsBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumeric: ~
            - SF\UtilsBundle\Validator\Constraints\MinLength: ~
```

ContainstAlphanumeric Class validator:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]$/i', $value, $matches)) {
    $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
}
```

MinLength Class validator

```
$min = 5;
if( strlen($value) < $min )
{
    $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value, '%min_length%' => $min));
}
```

So, when I submit a form and the input has the value "q", the validator MinLength returns a length error, but if the same input has the value "qwerty", the validator ContainsAlphanumeric returns an illegal character message.

Any ideas?

## **Edit:**

I changed Resources/config/validation.yml file to use the native [SF2 Contraints](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints.html) length validator:

```
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length: { min: 5, minMessage: "El nombre debe tener almenos {{ limit }} caracteres." }
        - SF\UtilsBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumeric: ~
```

And I descover a new behaviour: Some errors are displayed in twig templates with

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

and other errors using

```
{{ form_errors(form.some_field) }}
```

This is weird!

Comment: I should have mentioned that you should use the built in `Length` validator rather than writing your own. I'd also recommend the `Regex` validator. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems not I discovered, the validators did not return errors for all fields of the form and as I said when I asked, some errors saw them with `form_errors(form.widget)` and others with `form_errors(form)`
I solved my problem (but I don't know if this is the best way) using the [Validation Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) and returning the erros to twig.

In the Action:

```
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid())
{
    # Magic code :D
}

return array(
    'entity' => $entity,
    'form'   => $form->createView(),
    'errors' => $this->get('validator')->validate($form) # Here's the magic :D
);
```

And in twig template:

```
{% if errors is defined %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>
                {{ error.message }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks for help me :D

PD: I decided not to use error_bubbling to not modify each form field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the regex is wrong

```
preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]$/i', $value, $matches)
```

Matches any **single** character in the set `[a-z\d_]`

Notice the output here: http://regex101.com/r/eO8bF0

If you fix it so you are matching 0 or more characters form that set (so adding the `*`), it should work

```
preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]*$/i', $value, $matches)
```

http://regex101.com/r/rC4qO3

---

**Edit**
To answer your other question

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

This will show errors for the form itself, and errors that have bubbled to the form. See the documentation on **error bubbling** http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling

```
{{ form_errors(form.some_field) }}
```

That will show errors for the specific field.

Comment: That's correct, my regex was wrong, but the behaviour of validators it's still wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What you described is exactly what I would expect: "So, when I submit a form and the input has the value 'q', the validator MinLength returns a length error, but if the same input has the value 'qwerty', the validator ContainsAlphanumeric returns an illegal character message." And if you fix your regex, you would not have a validation error for 'qwerty' because it is at least 5 characters and matches your regex.

Comment: So please explain what you expect, because I don't know what you mean by "wrong"

Comment: With "wrong" i mean the behaviour of validators are wrong, because not always returns the messages.